# Clojure filter sequence of maps for a value in a list

Tags: clojure

Trying to filter a sequence of maps that have a value for a key in a list of values.

Trying to do something like this

```
=> (filter (fn [foo]
           #(some(:x foo) ["0000", "2222"])) 
           [{ :y "y" :x "0000"} {:y "y" :z "z" :x "1111"} {:y "y" :z "z" :x "2222"}])

; I want to return this
=> [{:y "y" :z "z" :x "1111"}]
```

edit: fixed typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces the desired output:

```
(filter #(not (#{"0000", "2222"} (:x %)))
        [{:y "y" :x "0000"}
         {:y "y" :z "z" :x "1111"}
         {:y "y" :z "z" :x "2222"}])
=> ({:y "y", :z "z", :x "1111"})
```

This solution is using a *set* of those two strings, and testing `:x` of each input map for set membership.

I think you have a typo and some other issues in your filter predicate example. I fixed the `"0000"` typo in this example to get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you, much simpler to read and understand. I was trying use something similar  with remove but was having the same issues as filter.

Comment: This should be able to be shorted with `remove`: `(remove #(#{"0000", "2222"} (:x %))`

Comment: `(remove #(-> % :x #{"0000", "2222"})` should work too.

Comment: `(remove (comp #{"0000", "2222"} :x)...) `. I always forget about comp.